# How to remove rows in dataframe and sum numeric values based on matching character values

Tags: r, regex, sum

I have a dataframe containing frequencies of words, many of which are just spelling variants of one and the same head word, for example, of the head word `oh` as in this sample data:

```
test <- data.frame(
  Word = c("oh", "ooh", "ohhh", "right-oh", "o'clock", "oohh", "o-oh", "o-b-i-t-r-y"),
  Freq = c(4762, 554, 15, 7, 7, 3, 3, 2),
  c5 = c("ITJ", "ITJ", "NP0", "ZZ0", "NN1", "ITJ", "AV0", "ZZ0"),
  Freq_BNCc = c(41555, 3856, 21, 931, 10, 8, 1065, 6),
  stringsAsFactors = F)

test
         Word Freq  c5 Freq_BNCc
1          oh 4762 ITJ     41555
2         ooh  554 ITJ      3856
3        ohhh   15 NP0        21
4    right-oh    7 ZZ0       931
5     o'clock    7 NN1        10
6        oohh    3 ITJ         8
7        o-oh    3 AV0      1065
8 o-b-i-t-r-y    2 ZZ0         6
```

I'd like to remove those rows that contain these variant spellings but at the same time update the frequency information in columns `Freq`and `Freq_BNCc` by adding the variants' frequencies to the head word's frequencies.

I'm not unable to accomplish this task but feel the approach is clumsy:

First, I remove from `test` the rows where the values in column `Word` match the variants (but not the head word) and store the result in `test2`:

```
test2 <- test[-which(grepl("(?!^oh$)^o[oh-]+$", test$Word, perl = T)),]
```

Then I update the frequencies in `test2` by summing the frequencies of the head word plus the variants in both columns found in `test`:

```
test2$Freq[test2$Word=="oh"] <- sum(test$Freq[grepl("^o[oh-]+$", test$Word)])
test2$Freq_BNCc[test2$Word=="oh"] <- sum(test$Freq_BNCc[grepl("^o[oh-]+$", test$Word)])
```

This way I obtain the expected output:

```
test2
         Word Freq  c5 Freq_BNCc
1          oh 5337 ITJ     46505
4    right-oh    7 ZZ0       931
5     o'clock    7 NN1        10
8 o-b-i-t-r-y    2 ZZ0         6
```

But the approach feels clumsy and error prone. Is there a better method?

Comment: Have you tried using string similarity measures, e.g. cosine, etc.?

Comment: No but matching the variants is not the issue.

Comment: Your regex return FALSE for the first entry of `oh`

Comment: You mean this regex? `grepl("(?!^oh$)^o[oh-]+$", test$Word, perl = T)`. That's intentional as I want to remove the rows with the variants but not the row with the head word

Comment: But you don't want to remove them. You want to aggregate them and get the sum...correct? It is different from removing. If you make the regex to include the original `oh`, then you can use it to create groups and sum per group as per usual

Comment: Ok, like how? ... The regex to get all of them is this: `grepl("^o[oh-]+$", test$Word)`

Comment: OK, I assumed "clumsy and error prone" included the use of regex. Regardless, I think it might make sense to simply replace the variants with the target word, then use `Word` to group and summarize.

Comment: @gersht That's a clever idea, the problem is that the `c5`values may be distinct. For example `oh` has `ITJ` but `oh-h` has `Av0`and so on.

Comment: You're right. Then maybe mutate + slice? I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I wrote in my comment above, it might be easier to simply replace the variants with the target word, use `Word` to group, and then sum the relevant values by group using `dplyr::mutate` and get the first group member with `dplyr::slice`:

```r
library(dplyr)

# Replace the variants with the target word.
test[grepl("(?!^oh$)^o[oh-]+$", test$Word, perl = T), "Word"] <- "oh"

# Group by `Word`, sum the relevant variables, and extract the first line of each gorup.
test %>% 
    group_by(Word) %>% 
    mutate(Freq = sum(Freq), Freq_BNCc = sum(Freq_BNCc)) %>% 
    slice(1)

#### OUTPUT ####
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   Word [4]
  Word         Freq c5    Freq_BNCc
  <chr>       <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>
1 o-b-i-t-r-y     2 ZZ0           6
2 o'clock         7 NN1          10
3 oh           5337 ITJ       46505
4 right-oh        7 ZZ0         931
```

Personally, I prefer string distance over regex for this kind of thing, so I might use `test[stringdist("oh", test$Word, "cosine") < .2, "Word"] <- "oh"` for the first part. But if regex is what you need then go for it.

Comment: Thanks, nice work. I'm not familiar with string distance and similarity measures but I'd be surprised if they'd be able to cope better than regex with the immense variation that I have for my data, which are from corpora of informal conversation.